# Python beautifulsoup - how to get item, loaded later in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am an amateur when it comes to PYTHON. I have a page where I want to download one thing - Town from website. This is link:
https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/echosonda-raymarine-dragonfly-5pro-najtaniej-w-polsce-1-CID767-IDHur6N.html
and Screen where is Town:

[image]

In browswer i have this sources html with town:

```html
<p class="css-7xdcwc-Text eu5v0x0">Bydgoszcz, <span class="css-1c0ed4l"></span></p>
```

I wrote this code but unfortunately it does not get this information for me.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link='https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/echosonda-raymarine-dragonfly-5pro-najtaniej-w-polsce-1-CID767-IDHur6N.html'
page1 = requests.get(link).content
advertisement = BeautifulSoup(page1, "html.parser")
town = advertisement.find('p', {'class' : 'css-7xdcwc-Text eu5v0x0'}).text.strip()
print(town)
```

It looks like the City is being landed later. And BeautifulSoup does not download it.Could you please help me how can I get the city name ?? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use Selenium WebDriver to execute the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored inside `<script>` tag, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use `re`/`json` modules to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/echosonda-raymarine-dragonfly-5pro-najtaniej-w-polsce-1-CID767-IDHur6N.html"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.__PRERENDERED_STATE__= ({.*})", html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("City:", data["ad"]["ad"]["location"]["cityName"])
print("Region:", data["ad"]["ad"]["location"]["regionName"])
```

Prints:

```
City: Bydgoszcz
Region: Kujawsko-pomorskie
```